# How to run Firefox in Protractor Testing?

Tags: testing, protractor, version

I tried to run the test, I get a blank white screen in Firefox browser and when I close the window, I get the following error.

Versions
Firefox: 45.5.1
Selenium standalone: 3.4.0
Chromedriver 2.30
Geckodriver v0.17.0

```
[10:10:40] W/driverProviders - Using driver provider directConnect, but also found extra driver provider parameter(s): seleniumAddress
     [10:10:40] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
     [10:10:40] I/direct - Using FirefoxDriver directly...
     [10:11:06] E/launcher - Unable to parse new session response:   {"value":  {"error": "unknown error","message":"Failed to decode response from    marionette","stacktrace":"stack backtrace:\n 0:  0x4bd56f - <no info>\n 1: 0x4b
  dcc9 - <no info>\n   2:           0x449980 - <no info>\n   3:               0x4207bc
  - <no info>\n   4:           0x405e47 - <no info>\n   5:                0x6db3d9 -  <
    no info>\n   6:           0x417847 - <no info>\n   7:           0x6d56d3 - <no i
nfo>\n   8:         0x77a359cd - BaseThreadInitThunk"}}
   [10:11:06] E/launcher - WebDriverError: Unable to parse new session response: {"
value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"Failed to decode response from    marion
ette","stacktrace":"stack backtrace:\n   0:           0x4bd56f -  <no          info>\n   1
 :           0x4bdcc9 - <no info>\n   2:           0x449980 - <no info>\n   3:
    0x4207bc - <no info>\n   4:           0x405e47 - <no info>\n   5:
0x6db3d9 - <no info>\n   6:           0x417847 - <no info>\n   7:
 0x6d56d3 - <no info>\n   8:         0x77a359cd - BaseThreadInitThunk"}}
at WebDriverError (C:\npm\node_modules\protrac
    tor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:27:5)
at doSend.then.response (C:npm\node_modules\p
 rotractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:445:19)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
 From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
at Function.createSession (C:\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:777:24)
at Function.createSession (C:\npm\node_modules
 \protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\firefox\index.js:640:55)
  at Direct.getNewDriver (C:\node_modules\pr
  otractor\lib\driverProviders\direct.ts:112:25)
 at Runner.createBrowser (C:\node_modules\p
  rotractor\lib\runner.ts:225:39)
 at q.then.then (C\Users\node_modules\protractor
\lib\runner.ts:391:27)
at _fulfilled (C:\node_modules\protractor\
node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\node_modu
les\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\nod
 e_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
at C:\node_modules\protractor\node_modules
 \q\q.js:556:49
at runSingle (C:\node_modules\protractor\n
 ode_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
 [10:11:06] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

Conf.js

```
exports.config = {
 seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
  baseUrl: 'https://localhost:288020/',
  specs: ['index_spec.js'],
      directConnect: true,
capabilities: {
'browserName': 'firefox'
}
},
framework: 'jasmine2',
jasmineNodeOpts: {
defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
},
onPrepare: function() {
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1366, 768);
}};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the latest version of Firefox (at least bigger then 51) to use Selenium 3.4 and the new Firefox (Gecko) driver. If you upgrade to the latest you will see it will work

Comment: Thanks I will give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with selenium 3.4, you cannot test with older firefox versions
If you use selenium version 3.01, 3.1 or 3.2, then you can still test older Firefox even if you run selenium 3.

- Firefox 48+: needs selenium version 3.0.1+
- Firefox 47: only works with selenium version 2.53.1
- Firefox 46: 2.51.0 2.52.0 2.53.0
- Firefox 44 - 45: 2.48.2, 2.49.0, 2.51.0, 2.52.0, 2.53.0
- Firefox 39 - 43: 2.47.1, 2.48.2, 2.49.0, 2.51.0, 2.52.0, 2.53.0
- Firefox 38: 2.46.0
- Firefox 32 - 37: 2.45.0

Comment: I am trying to downgrade selenium standalone. I downloaded the old jar and put into folder however when i am trying to run the webdriver-manager start, it still catches the new one and says its cannot find it. Therefore how do I manually change to new one. Any idea would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the version webdriver-manager downloads by altering Protractor's config.json file:

- Edit Protractor's config file: 
  **node_modules/protractor/config.json**
- Change the selenium version to whatever you need. eg. "selenium": "2.47.1"
- Run webdriver-manager update